# How to fix "ValueError: could not convert string to float"?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python code where the use can input as many numbers until they click enter without entering a number. The it does calculations to find the max, min, average, and total.

But I keep running into that error.

```
numberList = []

while True:
  enterNumber = input("Please enter a number (RETURN/ENTER when done): ")
  if enterNumber == " ":
    break
  convertFloat = float(enterNumber)
  numberList.append(convertFloat)

theMax = numberList[0]
theMin = numberList[0]
theTotal = 0.0

for value in numberList:
  if value > theMax:
    theMax = value

  if value < theMin:
    themin = value

  theTotal = theTotal + value

average = theTotal / len(numberList)

print("The numbers entered were: ")
for numbers in numberList:
    print(" ", numbers)
print("Max value was: " + str(theMax))
print("Min value was: " + str(theMin))
print("The total is: " + str(theTotal))
print("Average value was: ") + str(avg)
```

EDIT: I fixed it thanks to the person in the comments. However, there is a new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    print("Average value was: ") + str(average)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: `enterNumber == " "` is checking if the user input a space, not an empty string. `" "` is a space; `""` is an empty string.

Comment: @khelwood Thank you, it worked! But there's a new error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    print("Average value was: ") + str(average)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: That's because your parentheses are in the wrong place in your last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was noted in the other answers, you compare an entered string with a space instead of an empty string. But even with the mistake fixed, the user can enter a wrong formatted number. The cases are named as Exceptions, and you should handle it using `try/except` construction. Also there are `max`, `min` and `sum` functions. By the way, you can use `str.join` method to join a list into a string.

I would suggest such a code:

```py
numberList = []

while True:
    enterNumber = input("Please enter a number (RETURN/ENTER when done): ")
    print(enterNumber)
    if not enterNumber:
        break
    try:
        convertFloat = float(enterNumber)
        numberList.append(convertFloat)
    except ValueError:
        print("Your entered a wrong formatted number, try one more time.")

theMax = max(numberList)
theMin = min(numberList)
theTotal = sum(numberList)
average = theTotal / len(numberList)

print("The numbers entered were: ")
print(" ".join(map(str, numberList)))
print("Max value was: " + str(theMax))
print("Min value was: " + str(theMin))
print("The total is: " + str(theTotal))
print("Average value was: " + str(average))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the program fails to convert the `str` value to `float` value.

**Why?** your `str` value isn't in a float format, maybe it contains only characters and words but you need to input `float` string value and then the program will cast it into float successfully.

If you want to handle this situation learn about `try, except`.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from these lines:

```
enterNumber = input("Please enter a number (RETURN/ENTER when done): ")
if enterNumber == " ":
    break
convertFloat = float(enterNumber)
```

When done, the user inputs blank which corresponds to `""`. However, your code checks only for `" "` (a blank space) and so the input `""` gets passed to `float` and raises an error. A quick fix is to change
`if enterNumber == " ":`  to  `if enterNumber == "":`.

Also there's a further error down at line 31 where you call variable `avg` which is not referenced. I'd change it to `average`.